# How to store the certificate content into database on WPLMS - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to save the username, course taken and course teacher to a MySQL database when someone generates the certification, but I'm not being able to identify the variables used to generate those values.

Does anyone have the variables used by wplms?

As far as I can see, the variables are inside `the_content()` but I'm not able to expand it and see inside. If someone knows a way to check the content inside, please advice.

```
<?php
get_header(vibe_get_header());
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$print=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_print',true);


$class=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_class',true);
$css=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_css',true);

$bgimg_id=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_background_image',true);

$bgimg=wp_get_attachment_info( $bgimg_id );

$width = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_width',true);
$height = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_height',true);

do_action('wplms_certificate_before_full_content');
?>
<section id="certificate" <?php echo 'style="'.(is_numeric($width)?'width:'.$width.'px;':'').''.(is_numeric($height)?'height:'.$height.'px':'').'"'; ?>>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_before_content'); ?>
                    <div class="extra_buttons">
                        <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_extra_buttons');
                        if(vibe_validate($print)){
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_print"><i class="icon-printer-1"></i></a>';
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_pdf"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="certificate_content <?php echo $class;?>" style="<?php
                            if(isset($bgimg_id) && $bgimg_id && isset($bgimg['src']))
                                echo 'background:url('.$bgimg['src'].');';
                        ?>" <?php 

                        if(is_numeric($width))
                            echo 'data-width="'.$width.'" ';

                        if(is_numeric($height))
                            echo 'data-height="'.$height.'" ';
                        ?>>
                        <?php echo (isset($css)?'<style>'.$css.'</style>':'');?>
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                         <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_after_content'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO certificados (usuario, nome_professor, nome_curso) VALUES ('william', 'professor', 'curso')");
$stmt->execute();

do_action('wplms_certificate_after_full_content');

get_footer(vibe_get_footer());
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several tries I've manage to do that by storing the the_content() on a variable using `get_the_content()` function and filtering what I need.

If someone sees it and find a better solution, please advice.

Edit: I had to modify it in the end, but now it's working. Cheers.
Follow the working code below.

The statement above didn't work because I could not get the data I needed to, so I used this code to store `the_content()` after it was updated by the wordpress and not before.

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
$content = htmlspecialchars($content);
```

Older code:

```
$print=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_print',true);


$class=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_class',true);
$css=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_css',true);

$bgimg_id=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_background_image',true);

$bgimg=wp_get_attachment_info( $bgimg_id );

$width = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_width',true);
$height = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_height',true);

do_action('wplms_certificate_before_full_content');
?>
<section id="certificate" <?php echo 'style="'.(is_numeric($width)?'width:'.$width.'px;':'').''.(is_numeric($height)?'height:'.$height.'px':'').'"'; ?>>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_before_content'); ?>
                    <div class="extra_buttons">
                        <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_extra_buttons');
                        if(vibe_validate($print)){
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_print"><i class="icon-printer-1"></i></a>';
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_pdf"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="certificate_content <?php echo $class;?>" style="<?php
                            if(isset($bgimg_id) && $bgimg_id && isset($bgimg['src']))
                                echo 'background:url('.$bgimg['src'].');';
                        ?>" <?php 

                        if(is_numeric($width))
                            echo 'data-width="'.$width.'" ';

                        if(is_numeric($height))
                            echo 'data-height="'.$height.'" ';
                        ?>>
                        <?php echo (isset($css)?'<style>'.$css.'</style>':'');?>
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                         <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_after_content'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php

//Database Conection
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }


$content = get_the_content();
$content = htmlspecialchars($content);

$contentArray = str_split($content);

$counter = 0;
$trigger = 0;
$valueToDB = array();
$thisValue = 0;

while ($counter < count($contentArray)) {

  if ($trigger == 3) {

    $counter += 11;

    while ($contentArray[$counter] != '&') {

      $valueToDB[$thisValue] .= $contentArray[$counter];

      $counter++;

    }

    $thisValue++;

  }

  if ($contentArray[$counter] == 'w' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'x' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'y' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'z') {
    $trigger++;
  } else {
    $trigger = 0;
  }

  $counter++;

}

// $valueToDB[0] = Student's Name
// $valueToDB[1] = Course Taken
// $valueToDB[2] = Student's Email

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO certificados (aluno, email, nome_curso) VALUES (:nome, :email, :nome_curso)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $valueToDB[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome_curso', $valueToDB[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $valueToDB[2]);
$stmt->execute();

//

do_action('wplms_certificate_after_full_content');

get_footer(vibe_get_footer());

?>
```

New working code with duplicated verification:

```
<?php
get_header(vibe_get_header());
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$print=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_print',true);


$class=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_class',true);
$css=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_custom_css',true);

$bgimg_id=get_post_meta($post->ID,'vibe_background_image',true);

$bgimg=wp_get_attachment_info( $bgimg_id );

$width = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_width',true);
$height = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vibe_certificate_height',true);

do_action('wplms_certificate_before_full_content');
?>
<section id="certificate" <?php echo 'style="'.(is_numeric($width)?'width:'.$width.'px;':'').''.(is_numeric($height)?'height:'.$height.'px':'').'"'; ?>>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_before_content'); ?>
                    <div class="extra_buttons">
                        <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_extra_buttons');
                        if(vibe_validate($print)){
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_print"><i class="icon-printer-1"></i></a>';
                            echo '<a href="#" class="certificate_pdf"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="certificate_content <?php echo $class;?>" style="<?php
                            if(isset($bgimg_id) && $bgimg_id && isset($bgimg['src']))
                                echo 'background:url('.$bgimg['src'].');';
                        ?>" <?php 

                        if(is_numeric($width))
                            echo 'data-width="'.$width.'" ';

                        if(is_numeric($height))
                            echo 'data-height="'.$height.'" ';
                        ?>>
                        <?php echo (isset($css)?'<style>'.$css.'</style>':'');?>
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                         <?php do_action('wplms_certificate_after_content'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php

//--//--//--//--//

// Database Conection
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }


// the_content() stored in a variable
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
$content = htmlspecialchars($content);

// Split the content in an array to check all the information
$contentArray = str_split($content);

// $counter: iteration through the array
// $trigger: when the class wxyz was found
// $valueToDb: variable to store the values needed from the array
// $thisValue: array number of valueToDb
$counter = 0;
$trigger = 0;
$valueToDb = array();
$thisValue = 0;

// Checks for every letter on the array
while ($counter < count($contentArray)) {

  // If $trigger == 3, the record process will beggin
  if ($trigger == 3) {

    // Adds 11 more letters (the letters after class"wxyz") that the array has
    $counter += 11;

    // Adds the letters into a single word and stops if it finds an & (on the array)
    while ($contentArray[$counter] != '&') {

      $valueToDb[$thisValue] .= $contentArray[$counter];

      $counter++;

    }

    $thisValue++;

  }

  // This part checks if the class is wxyz, if so it starts again to record the word we need
  if ($contentArray[$counter] == 'w' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'x' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'y' OR $contentArray[$counter] == 'z') {
    $trigger++;
  } else {
    $trigger = 0;
  }

  $counter++;

}

// Check for duplicates in the DB before inserting the data
$checkDuplicate = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, nome_curso FROM certificados WHERE email = :email");
$checkDuplicate->bindParam(':email', $valueToDb[3]);
$checkDuplicate->execute();
$result = $checkDuplicate->fetchAll();

//That email already has this certification's course
$checkCourse = false;

// For each result, check if the certification was emitted
foreach ($result as $key) {

  if ($valueToDb[1] == $key['nome_curso']) {

    $checkCourse = true;

  }

}

// If the emails does not exist into the database or the email has not emitted the certificate before
if(empty($result) OR !$checkCourse) {

  // Insert into DB the data
  $insertDb = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO certificados (aluno, email, nome_professor, nome_curso) VALUES (:aluno, :email, :nome_professor, :nome_curso)");
  $insertDb->bindParam(':aluno', $valueToDb[0]);
  $insertDb->bindParam(':nome_curso', $valueToDb[1]);
  $insertDb->bindParam(':nome_professor', $valueToDb[2]);
  $insertDb->bindParam(':email', $valueToDb[3]);
  $insertDb->execute();

}

//--//--//--//--//

do_action('wplms_certificate_after_full_content');

get_footer(vibe_get_footer());

?>
```